# Sort objects in an array alphabetically on one property of the array

Tags: javascript

Let's say you have a JavaScript class like this

```
var DepartmentFactory = function(data) {
    this.id = data.Id;
    this.name = data.DepartmentName;
    this.active = data.Active;
}
```

Let's say you then create a number of instances of that class and store them in an array

```
var objArray = [];
objArray.push(DepartmentFactory({Id: 1, DepartmentName: 'Marketing', Active: true}));
objArray.push(DepartmentFactory({Id: 2, DepartmentName: 'Sales', Active: true}));
objArray.push(DepartmentFactory({Id: 3, DepartmentName: 'Development', Active: true}));
objArray.push(DepartmentFactory({Id: 4, DepartmentName: 'Accounting', Active: true}));
```

So I now would have an array of objects created by `DepartmentFactory`. How would I go about using the `array.sort()` method to sort this array of objects by the `DepartmentName` property of each object?

The `array.sort()` method works just fine when sorting an array of strings

```
var myarray=["Bob", "Bully", "Amy"];
myarray.sort(); //Array now becomes ["Amy", "Bob", "Bully"]
```

But how do I make it work with a list of objects?

Comment: You can pass a sort function as the first argument to .sort().

Comment: Since you're using `DepartmentFactory` as a constructor, create its objects using `new DepartmentFactory`, otherwise the array will be filled with a bunch of `undefined` values.

Answer (score 526, accepted):

you would have to do something like this:

```
objArray.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = a.DepartmentName.toUpperCase();
    var textB = b.DepartmentName.toUpperCase();
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

note: changing the case (to upper or lower) ensures a case insensitive sort.

Comment: I've come to your answer 50 gazillion times because i can never remember how to do this.
FWIW, my Linter always informs me of "gratuitous parentheses around expression":
`return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;`
Not gonna edit your answer, holding out hope I'll at least remember the linting thing :)

Comment: Found an issue with this code. Use a combination of lower and capital letters. ex. credit_card_no and City. The code does sort the list but words starting with 'c' are not grouped together.

Comment: we can simplify it to   return textA.localeCompare(textB);

Answer (score 269):

To support unicode:

```
objArray.sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.DepartmentName.localeCompare(b.DepartmentName);
});
```

Comment: For a case-insensitive version, use the following on line 2:
`return a.DepartmentName.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.DepartmentName.toLowerCase());`

Comment: learn something new every day - `localeCompare` is cool and has all browser support for first arg. Not bad!

Comment: @BenBarreth there is no reason to lower-case the strings. the whole point of `localeCompare` is to shunt the work of managing sort logic and locale quirks to the system. If doing a case-insensitive sort is normal for the locale, as it is in english, this will be done for you:

`"Z" > 'a' // false`
`"Z".localeCompare('a') // 1`

If you wish to deviate from the locale's default, you can send along overrides in the `locales` and `options` parameters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#Parameters

Comment: Just remember that this isn't null safe, need to check to see if "DepartmentName" is an actual string before running this otherwise the sort will fail on a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 51):

Shorter code with ES6

```
objArray.sort((a, b) => a.DepartmentName.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.DepartmentName.toLowerCase()))
```

Answer (score 22):

```
objArray.sort((a, b) => a.DepartmentName.localeCompare(b.DepartmentName))
```

Answer (score 14):

```
var DepartmentFactory = function(data) {
    this.id = data.Id;
    this.name = data.DepartmentName;
    this.active = data.Active;
}

// use `new DepartmentFactory` as given below. `new` is imporatant

var objArray = [];
objArray.push(new DepartmentFactory({Id: 1, DepartmentName: 'Marketing', Active: true}));
objArray.push(new DepartmentFactory({Id: 2, DepartmentName: 'Sales', Active: true}));
objArray.push(new DepartmentFactory({Id: 3, DepartmentName: 'Development', Active: true}));
objArray.push(new DepartmentFactory({Id: 4, DepartmentName: 'Accounting', Active: true}));

function sortOn(property){
    return function(a, b){
        if(a[property] < b[property]){
            return -1;
        }else if(a[property] > b[property]){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;   
        }
    }
}

//objArray.sort(sortOn("id")); // because `this.id = data.Id;`
objArray.sort(sortOn("name")); // because `this.name = data.DepartmentName;`
console.log(objArray);
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/diode/hdgeH/

Answer (score 10):

```
objArray.sort( (a, b) => a.id.localeCompare(b.id, 'en', {'sensitivity': 'base'}));
```

This sorts them alphabetically AND is case insensitive. It's also super clean and easy to read :D

Comment: This is also the only answer which mentions `'sensitivity': 'base'`, which makes a big difference depending on your application [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Collator).

Comment: thanks https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare#sort_an_array

Answer (score 8):

```
// Sorts an array of objects "in place". (Meaning that the original array will be modified and nothing gets returned.)
function sortOn (arr, prop) {
    arr.sort (
        function (a, b) {
            if (a[prop] < b[prop]){
                return -1;
            } else if (a[prop] > b[prop]){
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;   
            }
        }
    );
}

//Usage example:

var cars = [
        {make:"AMC",        model:"Pacer",  year:1978},
        {make:"Koenigsegg", model:"CCGT",   year:2011},
        {make:"Pagani",     model:"Zonda",  year:2006},
        ];

// ------- make -------
sortOn(cars, "make");
console.log(cars);

/* OUTPUT:
AMC         : Pacer : 1978
Koenigsegg  : CCGT  : 2011
Pagani      : Zonda : 2006
*/



// ------- model -------
sortOn(cars, "model");
console.log(cars);

/* OUTPUT:
Koenigsegg  : CCGT  : 2011
AMC         : Pacer : 1978
Pagani      : Zonda : 2006
*/



// ------- year -------
sortOn(cars, "year");
console.log(cars);

/* OUTPUT:
AMC         : Pacer : 1978
Pagani      : Zonda : 2006
Koenigsegg  : CCGT  : 2011
*/
```

Answer (score 7):

Because all of the solutions here were presented without null/undefined safe operations, I handle that this way (you can handle nulls as you see fit):

**ES5**

```
objArray.sort(
  function(a, b) {
    var departmentNameA = a.DepartmentName ? a.DepartmentName : '';
    var departmentNameB = b.DepartmentName ? b.DepartmentName : '';

    return departmentNameA.localeCompare(departmentNameB);
  }
);
```

**ES6+**

```
objArray.sort(
 (a: DepartmentFactory, b: DepartmentFactory): number => {
   const departmentNameA = a.DepartmentName ? a.DepartmentName : '';
   const departmentNameB = b.DepartmentName ? b.DepartmentName : '';

   return departmentNameA.localeCompare(departmentNameB);
 }
);
```

I have also removed the toLowerCase that others used since localeCompare is case insensitive. Also I prefer to be a bit more explicit on parameters when using Typescript or ES6+ to make it more explicit for future developers.

Comment: Neither sort actually returns anything so no sorting is happening. Also you can shorten the ternary to use a null coalescing operator (??).

Comment: @RogerSmith thanks for the comment! You are correct, I mistakenly forgot to return the localeCompare result. The ?? operator was introduced in ES2020, so in 2021 I would have hesitated using anything that fresh due to browser compatibility issues with raw JS. Also quick note, ?? is the "nullish coalescing operator"  the null coalescing operator is xxx?.yyy... Its a minor semantic difference in names, but big implication in implementation. Nullish works just as weirdly as Falsey and has a slightly different precedence than ternary. I lean towards ternary for compatibility and explicit syntax.

Answer (score 5):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RcbeN/)

```
var DepartmentFactory = function(data) {
    this.id = data.Id;
    this.name = data.DepartmentName;
    this.active = data.Active;
}

var objArray = [];
objArray.push(new DepartmentFactory({Id: 1, DepartmentName: 'Marketing', Active: true}));
objArray.push(new DepartmentFactory({Id: 2, DepartmentName: 'Sales', Active: true}));
objArray.push(new DepartmentFactory({Id: 3, DepartmentName: 'Development', Active: true}));
objArray.push(new DepartmentFactory({Id: 4, DepartmentName: 'Accounting', Active: true}));

console.log(objArray.sort(function(a, b) { return a.name > b.name}));
```

Answer (score 2):

do it like this

```
objArrayy.sort(function(a, b){
 var nameA=a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB=b.name.toLowerCase()
 if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
  return -1
 if (nameA > nameB)
  return 1
 return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
});
console.log(objArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple function you can use to sort array of objects through their properties; it doesn't matter if the property is a type of string or integer, it will work.

```js
    var cars = [
        {make:"AMC",        model:"Pacer",  year:1978},
        {make:"Koenigsegg", model:"CCGT",   year:2011},
        {make:"Pagani",     model:"Zonda",  year:2006},
    ];

    function sortObjectsByProp(objectsArr, prop, ascending = true) {
        let objectsHaveProp = objectsArr.every(object => object.hasOwnProperty(prop));
        if(objectsHaveProp)    {
            let newObjectsArr = objectsArr.slice();
            newObjectsArr.sort((a, b) => {
                if(isNaN(Number(a[prop])))  {
                    let textA = a[prop].toUpperCase(),
                        textB = b[prop].toUpperCase();
                    if(ascending)   {
                        return textA < textB ? -1 : textA > textB ? 1 : 0;
                    } else {
                        return textB < textA ? -1 : textB > textA ? 1 : 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    return ascending ? a[prop] - b[prop] : b[prop] - a[prop];
                }
            });
            return newObjectsArr;
        }
        return objectsArr;
    }

    let sortedByMake = sortObjectsByProp(cars, "make"); // returns ascending order by its make;
    let sortedByYear = sortObjectsByProp(cars, "year", false); // returns descending order by its year,since we put false as a third argument;
    console.log(sortedByMake);
    console.log(sortedByYear);
```

Answer (score -3):

After try a little bit on this, and trying to make less loops as possible, I ended up with this solution:

[Demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/alexanmtz/pen/KBYXMY?editors=0012)

```
const items = [
      {
        name: 'One'
      },
      {
        name: 'Maria is here'
      },
      {
        name: 'Another'
      },
      {
        name: 'Z with a z'
      },
      {
        name: '1 number'
      },
      {
        name: 'Two not a number'
      },
      {
        name: 'Third'
      },
      {
        name: 'Giant'
      }
    ];

    const sorted = items.sort((a, b) => {
      return a[name] > b[name];
    });

    let sortedAlphabetically = {};

    for(var item in sorted) {
      const firstLetter = sorted[item].name[0];
      if(sortedAlphabetically[firstLetter]) {
        sortedAlphabetically[firstLetter].push(sorted[item]);
      } else {
        sortedAlphabetically[firstLetter] = [sorted[item]]; 
      }
    }

    console.log('sorted', sortedAlphabetically);
```

Answer (score -4):

You have to pass a function that accepts two parameters, compares them, and returns a number, so assuming you wanted to sort them by ID you would write...

```
objArray.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.id-b.id;
});
// objArray is now sorted by Id
```

Comment: He asked about sorting by DepartmentName, not Id.

Comment: I tried this and this doesn't seem to work on string columns... it worked on a date column. What worked was the solution from @omer-bokhari

Answer (score -4):

A simple answer:

```
objArray.sort(function(obj1, obj2) {
   return obj1.DepartmentName > obj2.DepartmentName;
});
```

ES6 way:

```
objArray.sort((obj1, obj2) => {return obj1.DepartmentName > obj2.DepartmentName};
```

If you need to make it lowercase/uppercase etc, just do that and store that result in a variable than compare that variable. Example:

```
objArray.sort((obj1, obj2) => {
   var firstObj = obj1.toLowerCase();
   var secondObj = obj2.toLowerCase();
   return firstObj.DepartmentName > secondObj.DepartmentName;
});
```