# sort array of objects based on string

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

Suppose we have an array like

```
var a = [
    { name: 'Tom', surname: 'TestAsIvanov' },
    { name: 'Kate', surname: 'Ivanova' },
    { name: 'John', surname: 'Alivanov' },
    { name: 'Ivan', surname: 'Ivanov' }
]
```

I need to sort this array by surname field based on a provided string, e.g.:

1. for `'iva'` the pattern array should be sorted as follows

```js
var newA = [
    { name: 'Ivan', surname: 'Ivanov' },
    { name: 'Kate', surname: 'Ivanova' },
    { name: 'John', surname: 'Alivanov' },
    { name: 'Tom', surname: 'TestAsIvanov' },
]
```

2. for `'a'` the pattern array should be sorted as follows

```js
var newA = [
    { name: 'John', surname: 'Alivanov' },
    { name: 'Ivan', surname: 'Ivanov' },
    { name: 'Kate', surname: 'Ivanova' },
    { name: 'Tom', surname: 'TestAsIvanov' },
]
```

So arrays should be ordered by string pattern provided. How is it possible to implement this?

Comment: newA.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (a.surname < b.surname)
        return -1;
    if (a.surname> b.surname)
        return 1;
    return 0;
});

Comment: @murli2308 what part of *I need to sort this array by surname field based on a provided string* you didn't understand? OP wants some kind of a filter, not only a simple alphabetical sort.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown It will work directly I don't think it will require filter. I added a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/mn1f4c89/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a simple sort script for that. I don't know if it is the best way because I had to use two `sort()` methods, one to sort alphabetically([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900824/1267304)) and another to simulate a `LIKE 'string%'`(comparing to SQL) to get your condition:

```
var queryString = "iva";

a = a.sort(function(a, b) {
    var s1 = a.surname.toUpperCase().indexOf(queryString.toUpperCase());
    var s2 = b.surname.toUpperCase().indexOf(queryString.toUpperCase());

    return (s1 > -1 && s1 > s2);
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle with full code](http://jsfiddle.net/bzLzkm7z/1/)**</kbd>

At least it worked with both examples you provided, but I'm not sure if it is all you need.