# Sort objects in an array alphabetically based on one property

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I know that there is a similar question, [Javascript - sort objects in an array alphabetically on one property of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900732/javascript-sort-objects-in-an-array-alphabetically-on-one-property-of-the-arra/8900922), but when I run step by step using this method it jumps over the sort.

I have an array of objects which looks like this in console:

```
0:{id: "3645256536754", name: "john", description: "man", children: Array(0)}
1:{id: "8672092533958", name: "alex", description: "man", children: Array(2)}
```

I must do a `forEach` on it but before I must be sure that it is in alphabetical order based on the `name` property.

I did it like this:

```
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
    var textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
    var textB = b.name.toUpperCase();
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
})
```

When I run it step by step it jumps over this piece of code, I don't know why. Any suggestions?

Comment: simply `return textA.localeCompare(textB);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the comment by @gurvinder372 as influence, you should do the following:

```
myArray.sort(function (a, b) {
  var textA = a.name.toUpperCase();
  var textB = b.name.toUpperCase();

  return textA.localeCompare(textB);
});
```