# Sorting an array of objects alphabetically

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of object alphabetically , to make things simple I am using the below example. In my typscript I do splice to insert and remove items from array object.

**Array**

```
  cars = [{
        id: 1,
        items: [{
          name: 'car1',
          description: 'this is car1 description'
        },{
          name: 'car2',
          description: 'this is car2 description'
        },{
          name: 'car3',
          description: 'this is car3 description'
        },{
          name: 'car4',
          description: 'this is car4 description'
        },{
          name: 'car5',
          description: 'this is car5 description'
        }]
   }];
```

**html**

```
<p-dataView [value]="cars" [paginator]="true" [rows]="5">
  <p-header>List of Cars</p-header>
  <p-footer>Choose from the list.</p-footer>
  <ng-template let-car pTemplate="listItem">
      <p-fieldset legend="Header" *ngIf="car.id === 1" [toggleable]="true">
          <div *ngFor="let _car of car.items">
              {{_car.name}} - {{_car.description}}
          </div>
      </p-fieldset>
  </ng-template>
</p-dataView>
```

**********************************************UPDATE********************************
Sorry I have one more layer

```
  cars = [{
        id: 1,
        items: [{
             Model:[{  
                        name: 'car1',
                        description: 'this is car1 description'
                   }],
             Model:[{  
                        name: 'car2',
                        description: 'this is car2 description'
                   }],

        },
           id:2,
            items: [{

               Model:[{  
                        name: 'car13,
                        description: 'this is car3 description'
                   }],
             Model:[{  
                        name: 'car4',
                        description: 'this is car4 description'
                   }],
        }]
   }];
```

I tried

```
cars[0].items.Model.sort((a,b) => a[0].name > b[0].name ? 1 : -1) //It did not work
```

also tried

```
cars[0].items.Model.sort(function (a, b) {
                var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase();
                var nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();
                if (nameA < nameB) //sort string ascending
                    return -1
            })
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8900732/1009922).

Comment: you have to loop in the html over cars and not car

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
cars = [{
        id: 1,
        items: [{
          name: 'ab',
          description: 'this is car1 description'
        },{
          name: 'cd',
          description: 'this is car2 description'
        },{
          name: 'car3',
          description: 'this is car3 description'
        },{
          name: 'aaa',
          description: 'this is car4 description'
        },{
         name: 'car5',
          description: 'this is car5 description'
        }]
   }];

  cars[0].items.sort((a,b) => a.name > b.name ? 1 : -1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Or we can simplify to:

```
 cars[0].items.sort((a,b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it most efficient to use a library like Underscore.js for utility functions like this:

[Underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/#sortBy) and specifically the sortBy method.

Add underscorejs to your project and import it into your component.

```
import * as _ from 'underscore';
```

Then call the sort method and pass the array of objects and the key to sort on.

```
_.sortBy(car.items, 'name');
```

When you add or remove an item from the car array, resort the car.items collection and reassign it to car

```
car.items = _.sortBy(car.items, 'name');
```

Then you can display as you are now, with the sorted data.

Answer (score 1):

naive sort with `Array.prototype.sort()`

```
cars.sort(function(x,y) {
  if (x.items.name < y.items.name) return -1;
  if (x.items.name > y.items.name) return 1;
  return 0;
})
```