# Sorting alphabetically in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an object which has both `numerics` and `alphabets` like below:

```
{
  cc:
    {
        text:"Vienna",
        text:"Austria",
        text:"Germany",
        text:"245",
        text:"121",
    }
}
```

I want to sort them and this is what I have done:

```
cc.sort((a,b) => a.text > b.text ?1 :-1
```

But it is not working.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298232/sorting-an-array-of-objects-alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

Your data isn't "valid" JSON as the property names are not unique.

The resulting object below will have a single property "cc" that contains a single property "text" with value "121". Each time you declare the "text" property you will supersede the previous property of the same name.

```
{
    cc: {
        text: "Vienna",
        text: "Austria",
        text: "Germany",
        text: "245",
        text: "121",
    }
}
```

You could store the values in an array and sort it.

Also, bear in mind that you are storing numeric values in a string so bear this in mind and research "natural sorting".

```js
const data = ["Vienna", "Austria", "Germany", "245", "121"]

data.sort();

console.log(data);
```