# How to implement these sorting functions to my situation

Tags: javascript, string, typescript, sorting, object

Hey please don't shut me down right away because I don't know "the basics" or whatever, if I'm here actually posting it's because I've tried for 2 hours to do this simple thing and I legit can't and need help

I've used the top posts of this thread [Javascript - sort objects in an array alphabetically on one property of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900732/javascript-sort-objects-in-an-array-alphabetically-on-one-property-of-the-arra) and of a couple more too, it never sorts my array of objects, based on the property I'm pointing out, I don't know if I'm missing something or not
this is what my array of objects looks like and I wanna sort them by the horaInicial property, which is a string that keeps an iso 8601

```
Array(3)
0: Appointment
area: "S. Eter"
data: "2019-05-23T12:40:55.155+01:00"
description: "Sprint CS WEB"
horaFinal: "2019-05-21T11:40:59.028Z"
horaInicial: "2019-05-21T11:40:59.028Z"
id: 17
__proto__: Object
1: Appointment
area: "S. Confiança"
data: "2019-05-23T12:40:55.155+01:00"
description: "AR"
horaFinal: "2019-05-21T16:45:15.448+01:00"
horaInicial: "2019-05-21T16:00:15.448+01:00"
id: 18
__proto__: Object
2: Appointment
area: "djdndjsnsnsnzznj"
data: "2019-05-23T11:18:24.596+01:00"
description: "xbxnxnsnsjsjdjdkssjdjsjsk"
horaFinal: "2019-05-22T10:42:46.770Z"
horaInicial: "2019-05-22T11:41:46.769+01:00"
id: 23
__proto__: Object
```

then I try sorting it with functions from the other thread, like:

```
    this.appointments.sort(function(a, b) {
        var textA = a.horaInicial.toUpperCase();
        var textB = b.horaInicial.toUpperCase();
        return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
     });

    console.log(this.appointments);
```

the appointments array comes out the same

What exactly am I missing?

Comment: you don't need `toUpperCase`

Comment: Yes I want to do it in Ascending order

Comment: I've tried different functions from stack, and none worked, I really don't care what it looks like or what it needs or doesn't need I just wanna get this done, how am I having so much trouble sorting a simple array :\

Comment: the appointments array appears to be sorted to your specification already.  Also I noticed your horaInicial values are not all in the same timezone, you can’t string sort them and have it respect the timezone.

Comment: @James nop, horaInicial on 0- 11:40:59 on 1-16:00:15 and on 2-11:41:46, isn't sorted by horaInicial

Comment: They are sorted by date.  Which is what they are.

Answer (score 0):

> You are not parsing the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). This means that what you are doing is comparing strings. Not dates.

In order to use JavaScript [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function and receive your expected output, you need to parse your dates inside of it. To sort them by your object `horaInicial`, you can do this:

```
yourArray.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.horaInicial) - new Date(a.horaInicial);
});
```

And this will return a desc array ordered by date, so to convert it to asc you can just use `yourArray.reverse()`.

**Look at an example:**

```js
let yourArray = [
{
  area: "S. Eter",
  data: "2019-05-23T12:40:55.155+01:00",
  description: "Sprint CS WEB",
  horaFinal: "2019-05-21T11:40:59.028Z",
  horaInicial: "2019-05-21T11:40:59.028Z",
  id: 17
 },
{
  area: "S. Confiança",
  data: "2019-05-23T12:40:55.155+01:00",
  description: "AR",
  horaFinal: "2019-05-21T16:45:15.448+01:00",
  horaInicial: "2019-05-21T16:00:15.448+01:00",
  id: 18
},
{
  area: "djdndjsnsnsnzznj",
  data: "2019-05-23T11:18:24.596+01:00",
  description: "xbxnxnsnsjsjdjdkssjdjsjsk",
  horaFinal: "2019-05-22T10:42:46.770Z",
  horaInicial: "2019-05-22T11:41:46.769+01:00",
  id: 23
}
];

// BEFORE SORTING THE ARRAY
document.write("Before:<br>");
yourArray.forEach((i)=>{
  document.write(new Date(i.horaInicial) + "<br>");
});

//SORT THE ARRAY
yourArray.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.horaInicial) - new Date(a.horaInicial);
});

// AFTER SORTING THE ARRAY
document.write("<br>After desc:<br>");
yourArray.forEach((i)=>{
  document.write(new Date(i.horaInicial) + "<br>");
});

// REVERSING ARRAY
yourArray.reverse();

// AFTER SORTING AND REVERSING ARRAY
document.write("<br>After asc:<br>");
yourArray.forEach((i)=>{
  document.write(new Date(i.horaInicial) + "<br>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you sort timestamps using alphanumeric comparison? Convert them into epoch timestamps and then sort using the resulting numbers.

1.Convert the timestamps into epoch -

```
 arr2 = arr.map(item => {
    item.horaInicialEpoch = new Date(item.horaInicial).getTime();
    return item; 
 })
```

2. Sort based on horaInicialEpoch

   `arr2.sort((a,b) => a.horaInicialEpoch - b.horaInicialEpoch)`

P.S Only use string representations of time when you need to present it for human consumption. When programatically using datetime, use the seconds since epoch.