# how to sort the time and display the messages in a correct order

Tags: reactjs

[image]

here the messages are displaying in a wrong order the sender message of `how are you doing?` should be at the bottom of the receiver message of `hi heelo` how to sort the time ? and here is the code ,  please help me thanks in advance

```
       { newArr ? newArr.map((m) => {   
            return  <div className={m.type === "sent" ? 'media media-chat media-chat-reverse' : 'media media-chat'}><p>{m.msg}</p>
            <p>{m.date}</p>
          </div>
          }) : null }
```

Comment: You haven't said what `date` is (number? Date? string?). If it's a number or Date, the `sort` callback should be: `.sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date)` or oldest to newest (`.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)` for newest to oldest). If it's a string, [see this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900732/sort-objects-in-an-array-alphabetically-on-one-property-of-the-array?r=SearchResults&s=1|116.8924) but basically: `.sort((a, b) => a.date.localeCompare(b.date))` for an ascending lexicographic sort (reverse `a` and `b` in the function body for a descending sort).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ newArr ? newArr.sort((a, b) => a.date > b.date ? 1 : -1).map((m) => {   
  return (
    <div className={m.type === "sent" ? 'media media-chat media-chat-reverse' : 'media media-chat'}><p>{m.msg}</p>
      <p>{m.date}</p>
    </div>)
  }) : null }
```

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where `a.date` and `b.date` are the same correctly. The `sort` callback should be returning `0` in that case, not -1.