# JS sort by predefined string values

Tags: javascript

I have an array of items that I want to sort based on the `category` property:

```
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  category: 'bar'
}, {
  id: 4,
  category: 'baz'
},
{
  id: 5,
  category: 'foo'
}]
```

What I want is to sort it based on the following order:

```
- foo
- bar
- baz
```

How can I do it with an array comparator?

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return ?
})
```

Do I need to give each category an `order` number and do `a.order - b.order`? Or there is another clever way to do it?

Comment: You can just sort them [alphabetically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900732/sort-objects-in-an-array-alphabetically-on-one-property-of-the-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your order into an array and use `indexOf` within `sort`.

```js
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  category: 'bar'
}, {
  id: 4,
  category: 'baz'
},
{
  id: 5,
  category: 'foo'
}]

const order = ["foo","bar","baz"]

arr.sort( (a,b) => order.indexOf(a.category) - order.indexOf(b.category) )
console.log(arr)
```