# How to sort a list in alphabetical order in an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, list, sorting, react-hooks

I'm trying to sort the below rendered list of names into alphabetical order. I think I would use the sort method but I'm not sure how to do it? Here's what I have:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedPeople.length > 0) {
        let allSources = [];
        let sharedSources = [];

        const duplicateSources = selectedPeople.map(user => {
            return Object.keys(user.groups);
        }).flat();
```

Comment: You should add a tag for what language you're working in

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort objects in an array alphabetically on one property of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900732/sort-objects-in-an-array-alphabetically-on-one-property-of-the-array)

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = ["Ravi", "Aman", "Surya", "Rohit"];
arr.sort()
```

**OUTPUT :**   ["Aman", "Ravi", "Rohit", "Surya"]

Simply use:
**arr.sort()**
This will sort list alphabetical order.

Comment: where should I add 'arr.sort()'?