# How to sort array in Node.js by attribute and alphabetically

Tags: node.js

I don't know exactly how to explain it, but this is what I want. I have an array of domains also containing a health value and this is how I want to sort it. If the health value is unknown, currently healthKnown is set to false and health is set to 95.

```
aaa.com - 100
bbb.com - 100
ccc.com - 100
aaa.com - 90
bbb.com - 90
ccc.com - 90
aaa.com - (unknown)
bbb.com - (unknown)
ccc.com - (unknown)
```

*(there wouldn't be any duplicates though)*

In this, each set of domains with the same health are alphabetically sorted and unknown health is last. The array looks like this.

```
[
  {
    "name": "example1.com",
    "details": ...,
    "health": 100,
    "healthKnown: true
  },
  {
    "name": "example2.com",
    "details": ...,
    "health": 100,
    "healthKnown: true
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your attempt.

Comment: you need to use [`array.sort()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/sort)

Comment: @axiac https://pastebin.com/bBb2eiKH

Answer (score 1):

as per comments, array.sort() is probably the best way to go. See an example

```
let domains = [
  {
    "name": "a.example1.com",
    "details": "",
    "health": 100,
    "healthKnown": true
  },
  {
    "name": "c.example2.com",
    "details": "",
    "health": 100,
    "healthKnown": true
  },
  {
    "name": "b.example2.com",
    "details": "",
    "health": 100,
    "healthKnown": true
  }
]

domains
  .sort((a,b) => b.healthKnown && a.health > b.health ? 1 : -1)
  // credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/61033232/833499
  .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
console.log(domains);
```

Comment: That does sort it correctly by health, but it doesn't sort it alphabetically as well.

Comment: It's just an example. Add a subsequent .sort() ordering by name and you are done